# How do I conditionally compile for WebAssembly in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How can I make a config flag where I conditionally choose the `wasm32-unknown-unkown` target?

I printed the current environment using the following `build.rs`:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    for (key, value) in env::vars() {
        if key.starts_with("CARGO_CFG_") {
            println!("{}: {:?}", key, value);
        }
    }
    panic!("stop and dump stdout");
}
```

Which prints:

```
CARGO_CFG_DEBUG_ASSERTIONS: ""
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_ARCH: "wasm32"
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_ENDIAN: "little"
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_ENV: ""
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_HAS_ATOMIC: "16,32,8,ptr"
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_OS: "unknown"
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_POINTER_WIDTH: "32"
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_VENDOR: "unknown"
```

Normally I would do `#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]` but that probably doesn't work in this case because `#[cfg(target_os = "unknown")]` probably matches more than `wasm32-unknown-unknown`. Do I have to use a combination of `target_arch` and `target_os` for this to work properly or maybe just `target_arch`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is how [stdweb](https://github.com/koute/stdweb/blob/70f42102c1f664ef72ebbc8b35cee28d0cf51495/src/webcore/ffi/mod.rs#L1) is doing it:

```
#[cfg(all(target_arch = "wasm32", target_os = "unknown"))]
```

I tested it out and it looks like something simple like this works just fine:

```
#[cfg(target_arch = "wasm32")]
fn add_seven(x: i32) -> i32 {
    x + 7
}

#[cfg(not(target_arch = "wasm32"))]
fn add_seven(x: i32) -> i32 {
    x + 6
}

fn main() {
    let eight = add_seven(1);
    println!("{}", eight);
}
```

Conditional compilation in Rust allows for a great amount of granularity in that you can specify OS, architecture, etc. If you do not need that granularity then you do not have to use it.

There are `unknown` and `emscripten` OS targets for `wasm32`, so it would be best to differentiate the two if your code needs to be different for the two platforms.

Stdweb has chosen to use the more granular approach. If I were doing it I would follow what they are doing, but it seems like it would work either way.

Comment: There is `target_os="emscripten"` for `wasm32-unknown-emscripten`. https://www.hellorust.com/emscripten/ which may or may not be worth differentiating. Depends on what the user's code needs.

Comment: Sorry I had the target triple wrong in my mind.The triple has the general format <arch><sub>-<vendor>-<sys>-<abi>. The sys part of that is generally the OS which is emscripten in the case of wasm32-unknown-emscripten. Will update post to correct.